# Proper rbenv version applied

Tags: rbenv

Directory `~/.rbenv/versions` lists `2.3.0` without a release.

However, notwithstanding a `.ruby-version` file in the application's directory, that contains `2.3.0` if I state

```
rbenv global 2.3.0
ruby -v
```

I get the default ruby installed version of `ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]`

How can this be remedied?

Comment: What does `rbenv global` output? What does `cat ~/.rbenv/version` output? What does `rbenv versions` output? What do you get if you run `(export RUBY_ENV=2.3.0; ruby -v)`? Does `rbenv rehash` help?

Comment: Had done `rbenv rehash` and that did not change anything. Outputs are: 2.3.0, 2.3.0.  versions outputs:   `system  2.1.7  2.2.4  * 2.3.0 (set by /home/admin/.rbenv/version)`.  The `export [...]` command returns  the same system ruby 1.93 output as above.

Comment: What does `command -v ruby` output? What does `declare -p PATH` output?

Comment: [sorry for the hiatus in maintaining dialog]  `command -v ruby` returns `/usr/bin/ruby` while `declare -p PATH` states `declare -x PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"`  which I do find curious...

Comment: Yeah. You appear to be missing the `rbenv` path component entirely. That would explain why it isn't working. I suggest you look into the `rbenv` setup again and get your `PATH` set up correctly.

Comment: I had to add to my bash_profile `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH"` to get a ruby version changed. Something in the installation seems to have gone wrong...